# Buy ticket for person who is need attendance

Tags: ryanair

I'm planning to buy ticket to Ryanair flight. Currently I'm not shure 9 years old son is going to flight together. I'can't buy ticket for my son later since system requires attendant if person is to young.

Can I somehow buy ticket for my son later and tell system, that I'll be my son's attendant?

Comment: Have you contacted the airline to ask their advice?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to the Ryanair website this is possible:

[Ryanair Help](https://www.ryanair.com/ba/en/useful-info/help-centre/faq-overview/Travelling-with-children/Can-a-child-under-16-be-added-to-an-existing-reservation)

Short summary:

You have to book an "adult" ticket, then contact Ryanair via chat or phone to link the bookings (free within 24 hours after booking the second ticket, a fee is necessary later). On the day of travel, you have to check in online, then go to the counter at the airport in order for your child to check in (also free of charge).